# Adding a minimal key to a BCNF decomposition

Tags: database, normalization, decomposition

If I will add a minimal key to a given BCNF decomposition can it be no more a BCNF decomposition?

Formally, say I have **F** (group of functional dependencies), schema **R** and it's BCNF decomposition `{R1,R2,R3,R4}` and I will add another group **R5** to the decomposition which is a minimal key of schema **R**.

Will the new decomposition  `{R1,R2,R3,R4,R5}` be still a BCNF decomposition of **R**?

Answer (score 0):

Every minimal key is in BCNF since projection of F+ on it contains only trivial functional dependencies. As observed, e.g., by Koehler, any dependency preserving BCNF decomposition can be made into lossless by adding a table representing a minimal key. The resulting decomposition is still dependency preserving.

*Henning Köhler: Finding Faithful Boyce-Codd Normal Form Decompositions. AAIM 2006: 102-113*